# NSXMLParser converting CRLF to LF

Tags: macos, unicode, nsxmlparser, line-endings

I'm using `NSXMLParser` to parse XML in a Mac app. The file it's parsing has its line endings set as CRLF ([carriage return](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000D/index.htm) followed by [line feed](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000a/index.htm)). I can clearly see the `0D0A` in the hex of the text file using [Hex Fiend](http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/). But when the text comes through the parser to the delegate (via `parser:foundCharacters:`), that newline shows up as "\n" in the debugger. When I get the binary content of that string by calling `dataUsingEncoding`, I see that it's just the line feed.

Is there a way to get NSXMLParser to preserve the line endings in the source file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the XML spec [requires](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-line-ends) all parsers to normalise newlines; the original bytes representing a newline are not part of the document's infoset.

(What's the situation where you need to care?)

Comment: Legacy issues. It's complicated.